# Xcode simulator keypad doesn't appear after using keyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode

Simulating an app with an TextField control, when I click in the control, the soft keypad appears.  If I use the laptop keyboard to enter data, the keypad will no longer appear when I click on the control.  To recover the soft keypad, I have to select "Reset Content and Settings".  Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be bug in iOS 8. There are two fix to this problem:

Toggle between simulator keyboard and MacBook keyboard using [Command+K] shortcut key.

Reattach keyboard to simulator:

a. Open Simulator

b. Select Hardware -> Keyboard

c. Uncheck and then check 'Connect Hardware Keyboard'

OR simply press [Shift + Command + K] shortcut key

Comment: `command` + `k` did the trick. Once in the simulator up and running the app, I typed those keys, at least twice, and I could finally see the Keyboard. When I was doing that, up in the menu the `Hardware` option was highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

In the simulator you can toggle the state of the keyboard with the Hardware menu, scroll down to the keyboard menu.

Answer (score 2):

Command-K will toggle the keyboard